# thunderbird not installed so not removed (when it clearly is)

Tags: apt, uninstall, thunderbird

I'm trying to remove thunderbird from Ubuntu 23.04 but to no avail. Same issue with trying to purge it. In both cases, I get the following message

```
Package 'thunderbird' is not installed, so not removed
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
```

I also went to the snap store to try and uninstall it there, but I only see an option to install. Trying to `locate thunderbird` returns a pretty long list (appended at the end, minus cache entries due to word limit), and I can still launch thunderbird so clearly it is installed. Do I have any options besides manually removing it from everywhere that `locate` points me to? Should I even be doing that?

```
/home/username/.thunderbird
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/.parentlock
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/AlternateServices.txt
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/SiteSecurityServiceState.txt
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/abook.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/addonStartup.json.lz4
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/addons.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/blist.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/calendar-data
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/calendar-data/local.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/cert9.db
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/compatibility.ini
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/cookies.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/crashes
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/crashes/events
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/datareporting
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/datareporting/archived
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/datareporting/archived/2023-04
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/datareporting/archived/2023-04/1680717316251.86ba53c8-50e7-440a-91ba-cb513140c858.new-profile.jsonlz4
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/datareporting/archived/2023-04/1680717316258.945a698a-253b-44d2-a714-b3095ddca811.main.jsonlz4
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/datareporting/archived/2023-04/1680717316259.28788b43-8a2e-4ef2-8318-80ec3c95bf3f.first-shutdown.jsonlz4
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/datareporting/session-state.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/directoryTree.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/encrypted-openpgp-passphrase.txt
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/extension-preferences.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/extensions.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/favicons.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/global-messages-db.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/history.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/key4.db
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/lock
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/mailViews.dat
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/minidumps
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/openpgp.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/permissions.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/pkcs11.txt
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/places.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/prefs.js
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/saved-telemetry-pings
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/saved-telemetry-pings/28788b43-8a2e-4ef2-8318-80ec3c95bf3f
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/saved-telemetry-pings/86ba53c8-50e7-440a-91ba-cb513140c858
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/saved-telemetry-pings/945a698a-253b-44d2-a714-b3095ddca811
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/search.json.mozlz4
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/security_state
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/sessionCheckpoints.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/storage
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/storage.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/storage/ls-archive.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/storage/permanent
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/storage/permanent/chrome
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/storage/permanent/chrome/.metadata-v2
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/storage/permanent/chrome/idb
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/storage/permanent/chrome/idb/3870112724rsegmnoittet-es.files
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/storage/permanent/chrome/idb/3870112724rsegmnoittet-es.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/times.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/830eebcx.default-release/xulstore.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/Crash Reports
/home/username/.thunderbird/Crash Reports/InstallTime20230328155238
/home/username/.thunderbird/Crash Reports/events
/home/username/.thunderbird/Pending Pings
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/.parentlock
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/AlternateServices.txt
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/SiteSecurityServiceState.txt
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/abook.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/addonStartup.json.lz4
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/addons.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/blist.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/calendar-data
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/calendar-data/local.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/cert9.db
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/compatibility.ini
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/content-prefs.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/cookies.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/crashes
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/crashes/events
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/crashes/store.json.mozlz4
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/datareporting
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/datareporting/archived
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/datareporting/archived/2023-10
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/datareporting/archived/2023-10/1698731335511.5a260879-8e7c-422f-a2cd-8fe174207caf.health.jsonlz4
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/datareporting/archived/2023-10/1698731335698.d8975c2b-4159-4962-85f4-a93181e9b30b.health.jsonlz4
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/datareporting/archived/2023-10/1698731335758.dcbf704d-78ef-4194-a624-d1a208f4627a.main.jsonlz4
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/datareporting/archived/2023-10/1698731335764.602ca0b6-1e76-45d4-847f-614c3d50a723.first-shutdown.jsonlz4
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/datareporting/session-state.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/datareporting/state.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/directoryTree.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/encrypted-openpgp-passphrase.txt
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/extension-preferences.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/extensions.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/favicons.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/formhistory.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/global-messages-db.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/handlers.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/history.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/key4.db
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/lock
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/mailViews.dat
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/minidumps
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/openpgp.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/permissions.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/pkcs11.txt
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/places.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/prefs.js
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/saved-telemetry-pings
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/saved-telemetry-pings/587ab3cb-609a-4dc7-b867-a82f468eb23e
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/saved-telemetry-pings/5a260879-8e7c-422f-a2cd-8fe174207caf
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/saved-telemetry-pings/602ca0b6-1e76-45d4-847f-614c3d50a723
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/saved-telemetry-pings/605ad14d-d8e1-4bbe-a1a5-2f72ad62a3b4
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/saved-telemetry-pings/81490153-f28e-47f2-927b-b0d4405c6b98
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/saved-telemetry-pings/a46dbe81-82c8-417f-a59b-6cb0cbb0f647
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/saved-telemetry-pings/a5df3d76-bf3a-48ec-919e-0ffab2627e9b
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/saved-telemetry-pings/b0b8d3c0-8485-40e0-a56f-515dea242d45
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/saved-telemetry-pings/c63fc90e-6db1-4971-a54a-b26554202351
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/saved-telemetry-pings/d8975c2b-4159-4962-85f4-a93181e9b30b
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/saved-telemetry-pings/dcbf704d-78ef-4194-a624-d1a208f4627a
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/search.json.mozlz4
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/security_state
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/sessionCheckpoints.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/settings
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/settings/data.safe.bin
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/default
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/default/https+++addons.thunderbird.net
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/default/https+++addons.thunderbird.net/.metadata-v2
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/default/https+++addons.thunderbird.net/ls
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/default/https+++addons.thunderbird.net/ls/data.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/default/https+++addons.thunderbird.net/ls/usage
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/default/https+++www.google.com
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/default/https+++www.google.com/.metadata-v2
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/default/https+++www.google.com/ls
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/default/https+++www.google.com/ls/data.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/default/https+++www.google.com/ls/usage
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/ls-archive.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/permanent
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/permanent/chrome
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/permanent/chrome/.metadata-v2
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/permanent/chrome/idb
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/permanent/chrome/idb/3870112724rsegmnoittet-es.files
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/permanent/chrome/idb/3870112724rsegmnoittet-es.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/storage/temporary
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/times.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/webappsstore.sqlite
/home/username/.thunderbird/bo50c7ws.default-release-1/xulstore.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/gg59b6rw.default
/home/username/.thunderbird/gg59b6rw.default/times.json
/home/username/.thunderbird/installs.ini
/home/username/.thunderbird/profiles.ini
/home/username/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gnome-software/icons/56b810e86e55b9202f2bfdeabed9fa67c8a87aa8-thunderbird.png
/home/username/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gnome-software/icons/769cc5b0f634c85ab4bcfade854f1984b4c28e93-thunderbird.png
/home/username/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gnome-software/odrs/io.snapcraft.thunderbird-k1Ml1O9GzSO2QftV0ZlWSbUfQ78nN460.json
/home/username/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gnome-software/screenshots/112x63/0f8b5d2b2ad6d7fbfa03e44dca59d3ca1f4c7937b19eb19cd1dcbf7f89d32f15-thunderbird.png
/home/username/snap/snap-store/common/.cache/gnome-software/screenshots/624x351/0f8b5d2b2ad6d7fbfa03e44dca59d3ca1f4c7937b19eb19cd1dcbf7f89d32f15-thunderbird.png
/opt/thunderbird
/opt/thunderbird/Throbber-small.gif
/opt/thunderbird/application.ini
/opt/thunderbird/chrome
/opt/thunderbird/chrome/icons
/opt/thunderbird/chrome/icons/default
/opt/thunderbird/chrome/icons/default/default128.png
/opt/thunderbird/chrome/icons/default/default16.png
/opt/thunderbird/chrome/icons/default/default22.png
/opt/thunderbird/chrome/icons/default/default24.png
/opt/thunderbird/chrome/icons/default/default256.png
/opt/thunderbird/chrome/icons/default/default32.png
/opt/thunderbird/chrome/icons/default/default48.png
/opt/thunderbird/chrome/icons/default/default64.png
/opt/thunderbird/crashreporter
/opt/thunderbird/crashreporter.ini
/opt/thunderbird/defaults
/opt/thunderbird/defaults/messenger
/opt/thunderbird/defaults/messenger/mailViews.dat
/opt/thunderbird/defaults/pref
/opt/thunderbird/defaults/pref/channel-prefs.js
/opt/thunderbird/dependentlibs.list
/opt/thunderbird/fonts
/opt/thunderbird/fonts/.uuid
/opt/thunderbird/fonts/TwemojiMozilla.ttf
/opt/thunderbird/icons
/opt/thunderbird/icons/updater.png
/opt/thunderbird/isp
/opt/thunderbird/isp/Bogofilter.sfd
/opt/thunderbird/isp/DSPAM.sfd
/opt/thunderbird/isp/POPFile.sfd
/opt/thunderbird/isp/SpamAssassin.sfd
/opt/thunderbird/isp/SpamPal.sfd
/opt/thunderbird/libfreeblpriv3.so
/opt/thunderbird/liblgpllibs.so
/opt/thunderbird/libmozgtk.so
/opt/thunderbird/libmozsandbox.so
/opt/thunderbird/libmozsqlite3.so
/opt/thunderbird/libmozwayland.so
/opt/thunderbird/libnspr4.so
/opt/thunderbird/libnss3.so
/opt/thunderbird/libnssckbi.so
/opt/thunderbird/libnssutil3.so
/opt/thunderbird/libotr.so
/opt/thunderbird/libplc4.so
/opt/thunderbird/libplds4.so
/opt/thunderbird/librnp.so
/opt/thunderbird/libsmime3.so
/opt/thunderbird/libsoftokn3.so
/opt/thunderbird/libssl3.so
/opt/thunderbird/libxul.so
/opt/thunderbird/minidump-analyzer
/opt/thunderbird/omni.ja
/opt/thunderbird/pingsender
/opt/thunderbird/platform.ini
/opt/thunderbird/plugin-container
/opt/thunderbird/precomplete
/opt/thunderbird/removed-files
/opt/thunderbird/rnp-cli
/opt/thunderbird/rnpkeys
/opt/thunderbird/thunderbird
/opt/thunderbird/thunderbird-bin
/opt/thunderbird/update-settings.ini
/opt/thunderbird/updater
/opt/thunderbird/updater.ini
/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/HighContrast/scalable/apps-extra/thunderbird-icon.svg
/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps/128/thunderbird.png
/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps/16/thunderbird.png
/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps/22/thunderbird.png
/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps/24/thunderbird.png
/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps/32/thunderbird.png
/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps/48/thunderbird.png
/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps/64/thunderbird.png
/snap/gtk-common-themes/1535/share/icons/elementary-xfce/apps/96/thunderbird.png
/usr/local/bin/thunderbird
/usr/local/share/applications/thunderbird.desktop
/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/thunderbird-patch-inline
/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/thunderbird-patch-inline/README
/usr/share/doc/git/contrib/thunderbird-patch-inline/appp.sh
/usr/share/icons/HighContrast/scalable/apps-extra/thunderbird-icon.svg
/var/lib/swcatalog/icons/ubuntu-kinetic-main/48x48/thunderbird_thunderbird.png
/var/lib/swcatalog/icons/ubuntu-kinetic-main/64x64/thunderbird_thunderbird.png
/var/lib/swcatalog/icons/ubuntu-kinetic-security-main/48x48/thunderbird_thunderbird.png
/var/lib/swcatalog/icons/ubuntu-kinetic-security-main/64x64/thunderbird_thunderbird.png
/var/lib/swcatalog/icons/ubuntu-kinetic-updates-main/48x48/thunderbird_thunderbird.png
/var/lib/swcatalog/icons/ubuntu-kinetic-updates-main/64x64/thunderbird_thunderbird.png
```

Comment: Your thunderbird may be installed via different way. Try `flatpak list --app` to find out if it's flatpak, `snap list` for snap package, or find out if there's a shortcut file in `.local/share/applications` for the portable package (e.g., tarball, AppImage).

Comment: If it's a *snap* package, it will show when you list them (ie. `snap list`), and can be removed with `snap remove thunderbird`. If you `whereis thunderbird` you'll be shown where it runs from, allowing you to look using `dpkg -S` etc...  (*snap* and other packages can often be detected by the result from the `whereis`  with *appimage* often highlighted by non-standard location)

Comment: Why don't you provide the output of the `locate thunderbird` command?

Comment: Thank you all for your response. @mook765: I've updated the question with the result of `locate`.

Comment: The files under **/opt** hint strongly towards that there is a manually installed version of Thunderbird. Neither the apt package management nor snap install to the **/opt** directory.

Comment: Also `/usr/local/bin/thunderbird`. The directory is reserved for manually-installed (not package manager) software. Looks like you have tried to install Thunderbird several different ways, and have lost track of which you are using. No package manager will remove files from `/usr/local/bin/thunderbird` since it didn't put them there. Use `rm`

Answer (score 0):

**Update**

As you now provided the output of (presumably) the command `locate thunderbird`, it is clear that this concerns a custom install, outside of APT or SNAP. With custom installs, it is a convention to place the binaries under `/opt`. The person or procedure, probably the installer from Mozilla, that performed the install, properly adhered to this convention.

So to uninstall your version of thunderbird (yuo need to do this with `sudo` priviledges)

1. Remove the desktop launcher `/usr/local/share/applications/thunderbird.desktop`.
2. Remove the executable `/usr/local/bin/thunderbird`

Already now, you will not anymore 'see' thunderbird, i.e., will not be able to launch it the usual ways. The remaining clears disk space.

3. Remove the application binaries by removing the directory `/opt/thunderbird`.

Anything located under `/home/username` are user configuration data. This is never removed by any install procedure, and must be removed by the user if desired.

Anything under `snap` comes from SNAP installs, likely from installing a SNAP of the elementary theme.

** Original answer **
In Ubuntu, using the software center to install applications will install them in one of two ways, either as 1) a `.deb` package using the APT package management system or 2) as a snap, using the SNAP package management system.

If Thunderbird is still there after you tried removing it using the Software center, or using `sudo apt remove …` or `snap remove …`, then clearly your application was not installed using any of these package management systems.

Then, you or your system administrators are the only persons on earth that can know how you installed the application. For all other people, it remains guessing, especially if you do not provide specific information in your question (no information on the command you used to uninstall, no information on what `locate` returns, etc.). So therefore any answer has to remain generic: you need to determine how you installed the package, then uninstall accordingly. That could, in the worst case, indeed involve manually removing the installed files.

Comment: Thank you for your response. I've updated the question with the result of `locate`. To answer your other question, this is my personal computer and the only time thunderbird might have been installed is while installing ubuntu.

Comment: Maybe something broke when I upgraded from kinetic to lunar? I don't know.